# Transfer Data to WebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift4

I'm trying to transfer data to the `WebView` by clicking on the cell with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "App", bundle: nil)
  let popup = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "taskWebVieww")
as! taskWebView

  popup.taskVar = ("https://example.com/m_task?id="+self.tskid[indexPath.row]
+"&uid="+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")!)
  self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So it's really OK but I'm getting correct data only to the next click.
Firstly it's nill, secondly, it's opening the first value, and so so

**WebView code:**

```
var taskVar: String = "undefined"

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
  webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:taskVar)!))
  super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `webView.loadRequest()` in `viewDidAppear` instead? I think at the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the `taskVar` variable has not been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **didSelectRowAt** instead of **didDeselectRowAt**